Keep Hyperlinks from the Model in a document generated by EA
I'm currently working on creating a document and I would like to keep the hyperlinks created on the model.
I'm using a fragment that runs a query to populate the table as shown in the image below. The query used is the following:
SELECT obj.ea_guid & obj.Name as [name-Hyperlink]
From t_object obj
Where Package_ID=#PACKAGEID# and Stereotype='block'


At the moment, there are already hyperlinks made in the model that link to the Countries elements, and I would like to keep those in the document to facilitate the navigation of the document.


I've tried the common approach used while working with hyperlinks in EA, but in this case, it is not working. When clicking on the hyperlinks in the document, instead of going to the table where they are referenced, it goes to the very top of the document.
